# How can I auto-increment a column based on a combined index of two columns in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, auto-increment

I have a C# entity class:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerTicketNumber { get; set; }    
}
```

And in the Context OnModelCreating method:

```
builder.Entity<Ticket>().HasIndex(e => new { e.CustomerId, e.CustomerTicketNumber }).IsUnique();
```

How can I make the CustomerTicketNumber automatically increment but only considering the values already allocated to that particular customer?